# Menu is darkened and not enabled in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

Sometimes after navigating between screens in the iOS app, on iPad, I get this:

[image]

The side menu is suddenly dark and doesn't respond to taps anymore.

If I go for the hamburger menu, I get this:

[image]

but still not working.

I still haven't found a way to reproduce this on purpose, I'll edit this question when I do.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)